# Field Service Mobile Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, datetime

My requirement is to provide ETA(Estimated time of Arrival) to my customer.

**So the ETA should be greater or equal to current date/time**.

**If ETA is less than Current Date/time, it should throw an error saying "ETA cannot be in the past"**.

What I am not understanding is when I inserted the formula,

```
 "{!EnterETA}>={!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}"
```

in the Validate Input Section of the Screen element and passed the current date/time, it's not showing any error,

but when I used the decision screen and included the condition `{!EnterETA} Greater than or equal {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}` and then passed current date/time, it is showing the error "ETA cannot be in the past".

In both scenarios, formula is the same. It is working as expected for past and future ETA in both the scenarios but while passing the current date/time, it is working as expected only in the first scenario and not in the second one. Could you please guide me on this why the second scenario is not working as expected with current date/time?

Comment: Enter ETA is the date/time component added in the screen elemeent

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Overflow (SFSE)! *Firstly*, please add any additional information as an Edit to your question and not as a comment. You will find "Share Edit  Follow Flag" at the bottom left of every post - just click "Edit." *Secondly*, please separate all of your text into multiple paragraphs. In the SE editor you need to press Enter twice to start a new paragraph. Also, you can use the SE editor options to format your `formula as code`. It is difficult to read in one huge paragraph.